I have a transit in Riyadh diffirent airlines but same terminal with layover of 2 hours
I’m traveling to Rome from Dubai with a transit in Riyadh of 2 hours
Transiting in same terminal but different airlines
No checked in baggage.
Dubai - Riyadh on Flynas
Riyadh - Rome on Wizz air

Do I need a transit visa?
I’m resident in UAE and holding a Comoros passport does it make sense ?

